# How to scrape out all of the items in dictionary - Python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, nested

I'm working on a 'bookmarks' related app. I have a dictionary data that contains all of the bookmarks from the browser. The input looks like this:

```py
data = {
    "bookmarks_tab": {
        'children': [
            # This parent folder contains multiple nested folders, eg:
            {
                'name': 'nested folder 1',
                'type': 'folder',
                'children': [
                    # Now this nested folder can have multiple nested folders!
                    {
                        'name': 'nested subfolder',
                        'type': 'folder',
                        'children': [
                            # So on and on
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }

        ],
        'type': 'folder',
        'name': 'bookmarks_tab'
    }
}
```

What approach should I take to find out how many folders (including nested sub folders) does the input have, including its `name`. Remember it can literally have any amount of nested folders.

Comment: use recursion and check type ?

Comment: You should be specific in two ways: first, what code have you tried, and why does it not give you the expected result? Secondly, how do you expect the count to work - that is, if I have three nested subfolders with five items at the root folder, should the count be 3, 8, 9, something else? Giving precise inputs and expected outputs is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this. Recursively look through the bookmarks - if you're dealing with a folder then pass it back into the same function, counting the results as you go. Presumably in this use case you won't run into an input-too-large issue.

```
def process_bookmarks(bookmarks: dict) -> list:
    if bookmarks.get("type") == "folder":
        return 1 + sum(process_bookmarks(child) for child in bookmarks.get("children", []))
    else:
        return 0
```

If you want a list of all the 'folder' items, you can do something similarly:

```
def process_bookmarks(bookmarks: dict) -> list:
    folders = []
    children = bookmarks.pop("children", [])
    if bookmarks.get("type") == "folder":
        for child in children:
            folders.extend(process_bookmarks(child)
        folders.append(bookmarks)  # Note 'children' key has been removed!
    return folders
```

This will not return any of the child bookmarks - only the folders. It's easy enough to add an `else` clause though that appends a child to the output list.

If you're just interested in returning one element of the folder, you can do it one of two ways. Either this on the output of above:

```
names = [b.get("name") for b in process_bookmarks(bookmarks)]
```

Which reprocesses the entire list of returned folders, or:

```
def process_bookmarks(bookmarks: dict) -> List[str]:
    folders = []
    children = bookmarks.pop("children", [])
    if bookmarks.get("type") == "folder":
        for child in children:
            folders.extend(process_bookmarks(child)
        folders.append(bookmarks.get("name"))
    return folders

result = process_bookmarks(data.get("bookmarks_tab", dict()))
```

Which drops all the data besides the folder 'name'.

Some important notes:

- Python has a maximum recursion depth. If your bookmarks are nested past this depth, this approach doesn't work.
- `extend()` copies the original and extended list into a new list. This means if you start with a list of length 10 and extend it by 1 it takes 11 operations. Similarly, if you start with a list of length 10 and extend it by 10, it takes 20 operations. If you have a structure that has three nested folders, it will take `1 + (1 + 1) + (1 + 2) = 6` operations. For this application this probably doesn't matter - but it might if you are processing gigantic results.
- If you just return dictionaries, note that your dictionaries will still include the original data. So if I have three nested folders, and I recurse one layer down and return in my result that dictionary appended to a list of the dictionary two layers down, the total data is three dictionaries worth. I mention this not for performance, but because the output looks like this:

```
dx = [
    {"a": [{"b": ["c": []]]},
    {"b": ["c": []]]},
    {"c": []},
]
```

Not this:

```
dx = [{"a": []},
    {"b": []},
    {"c": []},
]
```

If you go on to use this list for processing (that is, a list of dictionaries describing folders instead of a list of names), be cautious that this extra data doesn't confuse whatever algorithm you're running it through.

Comment: But, as I mentioned i also need `names` of those folder. It doesn't seem to return names.

Comment: @AidenEllis Added how you'd do that, a few different ways.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the big help. Finally, got what I wanted after working for hours on it and created a Python Module. Here's the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/AidenEllis/BookmarkParser) if you ever want to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You want a list of the names of all folders including sub-folders? If so, the approach to this is recursively looping through all items, checking if they are a folder and if they are, append their name to a list. For example:

```py
def find_folders(parent: list) -> list:
    # List of names of all folders found
    folders = []

    for folder in parent:
        if folder['type'] == 'folder':
            folders.append(folder.get('name'))
            folders.extend(find_folders(folder.get('children', [])))

    return folders

folders = find_folders(data['bookmarks_tab']['children'])

# Names of all folders
print(folders)

# Number of folders
print(len(folders))
```

Comment: Note that this fails to return a count, which is what the OP wants. It also does a lot of copying given that you're just looking for a count.

Comment: @NathanielFord well, since it returns all the folders name (in a list) then obviously it's the amount of folders there are. `len(result)`?

Comment: Sure, that works. Just be aware that you're copying the length of the list every time you `extend()`. Also be aware that `dx = {"a": 1, "b": 2}; for f in dx: ; print(f)` does not get you what your code here implies. Specifically, it returns `a` and `b`, the keys, not the values of the dictionary.

Comment: @NathanielFord What do you mean about copying the length of the list? And what relevence does `dx = {"a": 1, "b": 2}; for f in dx: ; print(f)` have?

Comment: @NathanielFord Yeah, you're right about it. I'm so confused , i don't even know what to do with this. You got any workaround?

Comment: @isaa_ctaylor i think by `dx = {"a": 1, "b": 2}; for f in dx: ; print(f)` he means the result is only going to give you the name of the folders BUT how are you going to access the data inside the nested folders.

Comment: @AidenEllis your original question was about retrieving the names of all the folders? Or did you want to put all folders in a list?

Comment: @isaa_ctaylor Open a REPL and plug in `dx = {"a": 1, "b": 2}`, then plug in the loop `for f in dx:` (next line) `print(f)`. You'll see your for loop is providing *keys* not *dictionaries*. As you state in your function `parent` is a dictionary. Your code won't work as-is.

Comment: @NathanielFord That is my bad, it should be a list of dicts. I have updated my answer

Comment: @issa_ctaylor I explain in more depth about the copying of lists when using `extend()`.

Comment: Upvoted! Though you have an input-case issue - whatever code calls this needs to extract the original list, it can't take the original dictionary input.

Comment: @NathanielFord I don't quite follow? My code works with the `data` variable unchanged from the original post, however I have to modify yours to get it to work (first reference the `bookmarks_tab` key then pass that into the function. Could you further clarify what issue you have with my code? I'm not sure we are both on the same page here